# How can i pair usernames with this leaderboard code?

Tags: python

```
with open("GoldScore.txt") as f:
    #reads scores from the file
    converted_list = []
    content_list = f.readlines()
    for element in content_list:
        converted_list.append(element.strip())
        converted_list = list(map(int, converted_list))
        converted_list = sorted(converted_list, reverse = True)
        #this takes the scores and puts them in order
    print(converted_list)
```

```
Output
[135, 101, 51, 45, 34, 23, 19, 12, 5]
```

I wanna output them as a string and put them in a text file next to a username like this:

```
135 User1
101 User2
51 User3
45 User4
34 User5
23 User6
19 User7
12 User8
5 User9
```

But i have no idea how to do this

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code fails due to a private file: you haven't show the file format, nor how you treat the names.  Your current processing logic seems to repeat steps to no purpose, so it's hard to figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  You should search for how to store a list of related things (likely a dict), and then sort that with respect to one attribute (user's score).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of a dictionary will be useful in the case.
Note: I am assuming that the file contains only the names of people in each line and you haven't given many details. We don't have any data/input, so I have given you an example you can modify it for your own use

```py
dic = dict()
fhand = open(GoldScore.txt)
for line in fhand:
    dic[word] = dic.get(word,0) + 1
```

Now sort them by looping through the dictionary using `for k, v in dic.items()` store the value like `lst.append([v,k])`.
now as the values are in the list, sort that list in reverse.

PS: I would have commented but I don't have the reputation.